# Bootstrap modal not working inside ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using bootstrap modal ([Link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes)) in my project but it doesn't seem to work inside ng-include

https://plnkr.co/edit/W3utfj7URejXpeJX524e?p=preview

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div data-ng-include="partial.html"></div>  
</div>
</div>
```

I tried to debug css and ended up in in this  [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855)

Seems some classes are not triggeriing when using ng-include
Has anyone faced the similar issue..

Comment: Have edited my question.Please find the updated one here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
data-ng-include="partial.html"
```

should be

```
data-ng-include="'partial.html'"
```

**Note**: Your plunker dosen't work because the reference to angularjs isn't https

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P143kL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to close it

1. html way: use (`data-backdrop="false"`) in button.
2. via script

   $('#myModal').modal({
       backdrop: false
   })

for more reference you can [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: I want to close the modal on clicking outside anywhere on the page.Its not closing if I click left or right side.

Comment: Sorry @Super User Not able to reproduce the issue in `fiddle` as there are many dependencies in my project

Comment: @forgottofly in that case we can't able to solve your problem, only we can assume solution.